# Bash Script to find all .zip files in a folder, search the .zip contents and move them to another folder

Tags: bash, zip

I need help to write a Linux script to find all the `*.zip` files inside a specified folder. Then, search for "`_xx.xml`" files inside the zip file. And finally move these zip files containing "`*_xx.xml`" to another directory.

Comment: Anything you've tried please?

Answer (score 4):

Try this one:

```
FOLDER='/path/to/somewhere'
ANOTHER='/path/to/another'
find "$FOLDER" -type f -iname '*.zip' | while read FILE; do
    unzip -lqq "$FILE" '*_xx.xml' >/dev/null && echo mv -v "$FILE" "$ANOTHER"/
done
```

Remove `echo` when you find it working already.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. I have tried the above code and found to be executing fine. The echo comments also displayed fine. But unable to find the required test files in destination folder.

Comment: Like I said you should remove `echo ` if it works good enough: `echo mv -v "$FILE" "$ANOTHER"/` -> `mv -v "$FILE" "$ANOTHER"/`

Comment: Sorry, I didn't noticed your comment below.

Answer (score 0):

Finding and iterating over all zip files in a folder:

```
for z in *.zip; do
    # do something
done
```

Show the content of the zip file without extracting it

```
unzip -l "$z"
```

Grep the content of the zip file

```
unzip -l "$z" | grep '_xx\.xml'
```

If this condition evaluates to true, move the file using `mv`

```
mv "$z" new_dir
```

Now all you need to do is putting these steps together ;).

Comment: If there isn't any file matching `*.zip`, `$z` is equal to `*.zip` which you probably don't want (I'd expect no iteration of the for loop if there is no archive). [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23995653/4974372) works as expected.